# Problemas con la adquisición de datos arduino a arduino

Tags: arduino

Hola buenas tardes colegas,
El proposito de mi post es para buscar algún tipo de ayuda respecto a la recepción de datos a través de un Arduino a otro, bueno la topología sería la siguiente:
Arduino esclavo(tx) y Arduino Master(RX)
la verdadera causa del problema está en mi Arduino Master (RX) en la recepción.
Les pasaré los dos códigos y las cadenas que se imprimen por si alguien gusta ayudarme, gracias.

Código del Arduino esclavo (tx)

```
void Impresion()
{
 char tam;


 datos_TX[0]=valor_tmp1;
  datos_TX[1]=valor_tmp2;
 datos_TX[2]=valor_tmp3;
 datos_TX[3]=valor_ce1;
  datos_TX[4]=valor_ce2;
 datos_TX[5]=valor_ce3;
 datos_TX[6]=nivel_bateria;



 cadena_TX="";

 for(int i=0;i<(sizeof(datos_TX)/2);i++)
{
  cadena_TX=cadena_TX+datos_TX[i];
 if(i<(sizeof(datos_TX)/2)-1)
 cadena_TX=cadena_TX+"/";
}

//tam=char(cadena_TX.length());
cadena_TX=String(cadena_TX);
cadena_TX=Marca+cadena_TX+Marca1; 
   }
```

la cadena la transmito en la parte o función que se llama imprimiendo()
esta es la cadena que transmite

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi código RX en el cual tengo mi problema, que es donde pierdo un dato y es el dato principal. En este código tengo uno para leer los paquetes paquetes_RX()
y otro que es Split() es para separar la cadena

```
#define UNIDAD 101
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> //Needed for GPS
static const int RXPin = 5, TXPin = 4;
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);

  int valor_tmp1=0;
  int valor_tmp2=0;
  int valor_tmp3=0;
  int valor_ce1=0;
  int valor_ce2=0;
  int valor_ce3=0;
  int nivel_bateria=0;
//Definimos la marca de cabecera de nuestra cadena de transmisión
char Marca = '@';

//Generamos la cadena de transmisión de datos
String cadena_TX = "";
String cadRX;
//Generamos un arreglo de datos de transmisión
long int datos_RX[7];



void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ss.begin(9600);
  //Serial1.begin(9600);

}
    void loop()
    {


     if (ss.available() > 0)
     {
      paquete_RX();
    }
    }
     void paquete_RX()
    {
    Serial.print(datos_RX[0]);
    Serial.print("/");
     Serial.print(datos_RX[1]);
      Serial.print("/");
      Serial.print(datos_RX[2]);
        Serial.print("/");
     Serial.print(datos_RX[3]);
      Serial.print("/");
     Serial.print(datos_RX[4]);
      Serial.print("/");
      Serial.print(datos_RX[5]);
         Serial.print("/");
       Serial.print(datos_RX[6]);
        Serial.println();
       delay(200);
      int tamanio;
      char buff[35];
      char tam;
       cadRX = "";
      if (ss.read() == 64)
     {
        tamanio = ss.read();
      //m=char(tamanio.length());
        ss.readBytes(buff, tamanio);
        for (int c = 0; c < tamanio;c++)
     {
       cadRX = cadRX + buff[c];

      }

     }
      Split();
     }
     void Split()
     {
     String valor = "";
        int posini = 0;
       int posfin = 0;
       int i=0;

     do
     {
        posfin = cadRX.indexOf("/", posini);
       valor = cadRX.substring(posini, posfin);
        posini = posfin+1;
         datos_RX[i] = valor.toInt();
       i++;

       }
        while (posfin >= 0);



       }//Fin de Split()
```

El código genera esta impresión y como pueden ver me comen ciertos valores
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hay miles de posibilidades de que falle cualquier cosas pero como primera linea revisa la entrada de datos individualmente tal ves encuentres un error

Answer (score 0):

Hola me parece que el problema puede ser de sincronizacion. En estos casos lo que se utiliza es el modelo productor-consumidor para sincronizar ya que un arduino puede estar produciendo datos mas rapido que lo que puede llegar a leer el otro. En una primera busqueda encontre esta libreria:
[productor-consumidor-github](https://github.com/suttonr/Arduino-Producer-Consumer-Library)

Comment: amigo pero creo que esa libreria es apra i2c, lo que pasa es que esto es solo un prototipo, el proyecto se basara en 4 esclavos y un maestro que estaran conectados con xbee, si la recepcion no la puedo hacer bien de un Arduino a otro tender problemas cuando tenga 5 arduinos entonces por eso es necesario corregir de manera exacta este codigo

Answer (score 0):

no te has planteado utilizar I2C? Yo creo que es una mejor forma de comunicarse entre dos Arduino. Mucho ojo con utilizar los pines 0 y 1 (Rx y Tx). Puede interferir en la carga del programa.

Mírate este artículo lo mismo te ayuda

https://programarfacil.com/blog/arduino-blog/conectar-dos-arduinos-i2c

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente. y no imprimas antes de leer.

```
void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() > 0 ){
    readSerial();
  }
}

void readSerial(){

    String readData="";

    while (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
      char inChar = Serial.read();
      readData += inChar;
    }

//Si quieres imprimir
Serial.println("Recibido Serial : " + readData); 

Split(readData);//Modifica tu metodo split para recibir la cadena
```

}

Comment: No se a que distancia estas trabajando, pero si quieres utilizar varios metros te conviene utilizar módulos rs485, puedes extenderte hasta 1200 metros con dos cables.